# A better way to operate (add and substract) with the absolute value of a numeric variable

Tags: c#, math

I need to operate with variables that can be either positive or negative values, in a way that a method should be able to add or substract its absolute value, but without changing its sign.

I have the following code to do something alike:

```
public static class FloatExtensions
{
    public static float sumToItsAbsolute(this float currentValue, float summedValue)
    {
        float currentAbsoluteValue = Math.Abs(currentValue);

        return (currentValue / currentAbsoluteValue) * (currentAbsoluteValue + summedValue);
    }
}
```

I can work with it, but I would like to know if there is a better approach.

EDIT: By "better", I mean more performant. And if there is no potential bugs I have not seen yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this code does what it is supposed to do, but you want it better, then you have to define what you mean by "better".

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Edited. By "better", I mean more performant. And if there is no potential bugs I have not seen yet.

Comment: You want _this_ to be faster? Are you sure _this_ is what's slowing down your code?

Comment: @Sweeper I do not want *this* to be faster as it is fast enough, but I also would like to know if there is a better approach to make it even faster, just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you spend a little time looking around the documentation of the [*Math* class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-5.0#methods) (which you are already using, so it is known to you already), you will notice that it offers a many handy functions. Among them a function to get the sign of a value.

Thus, instead of doing `v / Math.Abs(v)` to get the sign of `v` as values -1 or 1 (functional and creative, but cumbersome, and perhaps even prone to precision errors IEEE floating point operations might suffer from), you could just do `Math.Sign(v)` to get the sign.

With regards to bugs: I'd like to throw the ball back into your court and like to encourage you to think a little bit about the behavior of your code for yourself first. Note how your code is doing a division and a multiplication of a sum. Can you find values for *currentValue* where either the division or the multiplication might fail or yield the wrong result?

Performancewise, i really doubt this function is what would make your program slower than you desire. If your program is behaving slower than expected in some aspects, use a [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) to figure out the actual part(s) in your program that account for most of the performance costs instead of eyeballing and blind-guessing it.